# I have a problem with the backpropagation of custom set of trainable variables

Tags: tensorflow

I am training the neural network by selecting custom set of variables with

```
  tvars =  model.trainable_variables
  g_vars = [var for var in tvars if 'param' in var.name]
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator,g_vars))
```

the optimizer is

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
```

the gradients are taken with

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)
  loss = compute_loss_labeled(model, x,label) 
gradients_of_discriminator = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
```

the error is

```
InvalidArgumentError:  var and grad do not have the same shape[11] [1]
 [[node Adam/Adam/update_13/ResourceApplyAdam (defined at <ipython-input-1-ad3fd128f89e>:343) ]] [Op:__inference_train_step_normal_label_12257]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node Adam/Adam/update_13/ResourceApplyAdam:
model_1/param_9/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp/resource (defined at <ipython-input-1-ad3fd128f89e>:331) 
gradient_tape/sequential_1_1/conv2d_transpose_2/BiasAdd/BiasAddGrad (defined at <ipython-input-1-ad3fd128f89e>:337) 
model_1_1/param_9/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp (defined at <ipython-input-1-ad3fd128f89e>:332)

Function call stack:
train_step_normal_label
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that the gradients list and vars list have the same shape, in this case you are creating `g_vars` by filtering `tvars`, but `gradients_of_discriminator` contains the gradients of `tvars`. One way of fixing this would be

```py
tvars =  model.trainable_variables
g_vars = [var for var in tvars if 'param' in var.name]

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)
  loss = compute_loss_labeled(model, x,label)

gradients_of_discriminator = tape.gradient(loss, g_vars)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, g_vars))
```